# Correct way to do a generic interface method?

Tags: java, generics

I want to make an interface where I can do e.g.

```
public interface Getter {
  T get(String location);
}

public class IntegerGetter {
  Integer get(String location) {
    Object x = foo(location);
    if (!(x instanceOf Integer)) { throw Exception }
    return (Integer) x;
  }
}
```

what is the correct way to arrange the generics to make this work?  One option would seem to be to make T a type parameter of the interface itself, e.g. `Getter<T>`, `IntegerGetter<Integer>`, but since the parameter is only used on the one method it makes more sense for it to be a method parameter.  However, I have been advised that just having the type parameter be the return type of the method is dangerous, e.g. `<T> T get`.

Comment: What is `foo` here?

Comment: "but since the parameter is only used on the one method it makes more sense for it to be a method parameter." No, it doesn't make more sense. Use `Getter<T>` and `IntegerGetter implements Getter<Integer>`.

Comment: @bradimus the example I provided was minimal but in reality I'm building something that has a bunch of other methods unrelated to the type.  In this case the method won't be used by 95% of the users of the class, yet they would still have to provide the generic type parameter.  Should have made that clearer.  Do you still say that it doesn't make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have been advised that just having the type parameter be the return type of the method is dangerous, e.g. `<T> T get`.

It's no more dangerous than what you've already got.

Simplifying your `IntegerGetter` a little:

```
class IntegerGetter {
  Integer get(String location) {
    return (Integer) foo(location);
  }
}
```

You can define an equivalent class for `String`s:

```
class StringGetter {
  String get(String location) {
    return (String) foo(location);
  }
}
```

Assuming that `foo(String)` is the same method in these two classes, that it returns a result based purely on `location`, and it doesn't return `null`, at least one of the following lines will fail:

```
Integer i = new IntegerGetter().get("hello");
String s = new StringGetter().get("hello");
```

since `foo("hello")` can't be both a `String` and an `Integer`.

So, you may as well just have a single implementation:

```
class SimplerGetter {
  <T> T get(String location) {
    return (T) foo(location);
  }
}
```

which will fail in exactly the same circumstances as with the separate classes.

```
Integer i = new SimplerGetter().get("hello");
String s = new SimplerGetter().get("hello");
```

Comment: There's a difference if you're not specifying the type on invocation, e.g. `Object o = new SimplerGetter().get("hello");`.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically implementing an interface similar to [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html). You can take that as a reference. The interface needs to be typed with the parameter `T`, otherwise the `get` method could be used in an invocation context where it can return an object of *any* type.